# unable to add a radio button dialog to the Administrative Install sequence in a Visual studio Installer project

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-setup-proje

I can add a dialog to the normal install sequence with Radio buttons that can be used to control custom install behavior.  However when I go to the Administrative install sequence, the radio button dialogs (along with a number of other dialogs that take user input) aren't available.

Is there a way to force the radio button dialog to be available?  If not, why isn't it, and what can I do when I need the user doing the install to pick between 2 configuration options.

Answer (score 0):

An administrative install is basically an extraction of the files in the setup to some location. It is not an actual install - you won't find the product in Programs&Features afterwards. It's used for creating patches, for example, where administrative images of the base and the updated products are compared to create a patch. It can also be used for run-from-source applications, and that's when the product actually gets installed from the administrative image and the apps run from the administrative image location. That's why there are no UI choices - it doesn't "install" the product - it makes an image of all the files plus MSI that can be used for patching or (rarely) for run-from-source setups. It might help if you say why you want a UI choice in these situations.

Comment: If that's the case, [MS's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a48h5xkw%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) leaves a lot to be desired.  This description read like it was the version of an installer the admin would get if deploying it remotely; in which case the Mode A/B selection would still have needed to be explicitly selected.